# Bootstrap theme ugly looking font for inline literal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts, themes, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am developing a documentation using Sphinx and reStructured text markup. The theme that I would like to use is Bootstrap.

I have a lot of inline literals in my documentation and the resulting html font looks ugly because the inline literals are being rendered in monospace font without any anti aliasing. This happens both in Chrome and Firefox.

Any idea how to change to use better font rendering with this theme?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried *changing the font* for this style?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to change the font in the css file. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is due to the old version being used. Switching over to the latest version improves the font rendering.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid without minimal CSS/HTML knowledge there is nothing you could do, except trying other theme.

Vanilla Twitter Bootstrap is not really an *out-of-the-box* solution  and it requires some amount of customization and polishing. There are some *production-ready* themes around, based on Bootstrap, maybe you could find something, that suits you.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution. I was using the old version perhaps and the monospace fonts were looking ugly. I have fixed it by moving to the latest version.